# Perl DBI Postgresql: Returning undef for data that is there

Tags: perl, postgresql, undefined, dbi

I'm getting very weird results and I know their must be something small that I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to check and see if a row exist in a postgresql database table and on the first loop I get an actual value. On the second iteration of the loop and all iterations there after I get an undef. Why? Is there something I must do that I'm not doing. I'm not using prepare so I shouldn't have to call finish etc.

Any insight will greatly help me debug this issue.

Sorry the code is so nasty for now. I've been on a debugging hunt and made things pretty ugly.

Also sorry for the ugly sample output. I don't know how to format it well with stackoverflow.

Please not the "Select Name" printout in sample output. All iterations after the first returns undef.
The sql call in question is towards the end of the file. This is the line

```
my $selectSQL = "select name from crawler_url where url='http://www.maccosmetics.com$item->{'uri'}' ";
```

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;                # From CPAN
use JSON qw( decode_json );     # From CPAN
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
use Data::Dumper;               # Perl core module
use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak;
use Mojo::DOM;
use DBI;
use String::Util qw(trim);
use strict;                     # Good practice
use warnings;                   # Good practice

my $initialize = 0;
my $debug = 1;

&main;

sub main {
    my $dbh = connect2db();

    unless(defined($dbh)) {
        exit 1;
    }


    my $trendsurl;

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT company_name from companies where active=1");
    $sth->execute;
    while( my $company = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
        #print Dumper($company)."\n";

        my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url from crawlers where company_name='$$company{'company_name'}' ");
        $sth2->execute;
        while( my $url = $sth2->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
            #print " NOW ON URL $$url{'url'} ##########\n";
            $trendsurl = $$url{'url'};
            chomp($trendsurl);
            $trendsurl = trim($trendsurl);
            print "URL: ".$trendsurl."\n";

            my $json = get( $trendsurl );
            die "Could not get $trendsurl!" unless defined $json;

            my $parsed_json = parse_json($json);
            my $items = $parsed_json->{'sections'}[0]->{'items'};

            foreach my $item_hash (@$items) {
                #print Dumper($item_hash)."\n";
                my $category = $item_hash->{'name'};
                print "Lip Product Category: $category\n";

                foreach my $item ( @{ $item_hash->{'items'} } ) {
                    print Dumper($item)."\n";

                    my $selectSQL = "select name from crawler_url where url='http://www.maccosmetics.com$item->{'uri'}' ";

                    print $selectSQL."\n" if($debug);

                    my ($productCount) = $dbh->selectrow_array($selectSQL);

                    my $date = localtime;
                    chomp($productCount);
                    trim($productCount);
                    chomp($item->{'name'});
                    trim($item->{'name'});

                    print "Select Name: '$productCount'\n";
                    print "Item Name: '$item->{'name'}'\n";
                    print "Do they equal: ", index($productCount, $item->{'name'}), " \n";

                    print Dumper($productCount);

                    if( index($productCount, $item->{'name'}) == -1 ) {
                        my $insertSQL = "insert into crawler_url (first_seen,url,name,category,last_checked) values ('$date','http://www.maccosmetics.com$item->{'uri'}','$item->{'name'}','$category','$date') ";
                        print $insertSQL."\n" if($debug);
                        my $retVal = $dbh->do($insertSQL);

                        $insertSQL = "insert into urls (company_name,url) values ('$$company{'company_name'}','http://www.maccosmetics.com$item->{'uri'}') ";
                        print $insertSQL."\n" if($debug);
                        $retVal = $dbh->do($insertSQL);
                    }
                    else {
                        #We have seen this before
                        my $updateSQL = "update crawler_url SET (url,name,category,last_checked) = ('http://www.maccosmetics.com$item->{'uri'}','$item->{'name'}','$category','$date' )";
                        print $updateSQL."\n" if($debug);
                        my $retVal = $dbh->do($updateSQL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sub connect2db {
    return DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=xxxxxx", "xxxxx", "XXXXXX");
}
```

Sample output:

```
URL: http://www.maccosmetics.com/includes/panel_nav/catalog.js?CATEGORY_ID=CAT163&LOCALE=en_US

Lip Product Category: Lipstick

$VAR1 = {
  'uri' => '/product/shaded/168/310/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Lipstick/index.tmpl',
  'description' => 'Colour plus texture for the lips. Stands out on the runway...',
  'name' => 'Lipstick',
  'thumbnail' => '/images/products/56x56/M300.jpg',
  'header' => '/images/pnav/product/headers/pnav_M300_200x12_off.gif',
  'id' => 'CAT168PROD310'
};

select name from crawler_url where url='http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/310/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Lipstick/index.tmpl'

Select Name: 'Lipstick                                                                                                                        '

Item Name: 'Lipstick'


Do they equal: -1

$VAR1 = 'Lipstick                                                                                                                        ';
update crawler_url SET (url,name,category,last_checked) = ('http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/310/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Lipstick/index.tmpl','Lipstick','Lipstick','Wed Jan 28 21:15:40 2015' )

$VAR1 = {
      'id' => 'CAT168PROD34492',
      'thumbnail' => '/images/products/56x56/MX5G8N.jpg',
      'header' => '/images/pnav/product/headers/pnav_MX5G8N_200x12_off.gif',
      'description' => "Miley Cyrus\x{2019}s shade of VIVA GLAM Lipstick. Her super-sexy hot...",
      'name' => 'VIVA GLAM Miley Cyrus Lipstick',
      'uri' => '/product/shaded/168/34492/Products/Lips/Lipstick/VIVA-GLAM-Miley-Cyrus-Lipstick/index.tmpl'
    };

select name from crawler_url where url='http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/34492/Products/Lips/Lipstick/VIVA-GLAM-Miley-Cyrus-Lipstick/index.tmpl'

Select Name: ''

Item Name: 'VIVA GLAM Miley Cyrus Lipstick'


Do they equal: 0

$VAR1 = undef;

insert into crawler_url (first_seen,url,name,category,last_checked) values ('Wed Jan 28 21:15:40 2015','http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/34492/Products/Lips/Lipstick/VIVA-GLAM-Miley-Cyrus-Lipstick/index.tmpl','VIVA GLAM Miley Cyrus Lipstick','Lipstick','Wed Jan 28 21:15:40 2015')

insert into urls (company_name,url) values ('MAC                                                             ','http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/34492/Products/Lips/Lipstick/VIVA-GLAM-Miley-Cyrus-Lipstick/index.tmpl')

$VAR1 = {
      'uri' => '/product/shaded/168/34798/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Isabel-and-Ruben-Toledo-Lipstick/index.tmpl',
      'description' => 'Formulated to shade, define and showcase the lips in a rouge-y...',
      'name' => 'Isabel and Ruben Toledo Lipstick ',
      'header' => '/images/pnav/product/headers/pnav_MWWE1T_200x12_off.gif',
      'thumbnail' => '/images/products/56x56/MWWE1T.jpg',
      'id' => 'CAT168PROD34798'
    };

select name from crawler_url where url='http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/34798/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Isabel-and-Ruben-Toledo-Lipstick/index.tmpl'

Select Name: ''


Item Name: 'Isabel and Ruben Toledo Lipstick '

Do they equal: 0

$VAR1 = undef;

insert into crawler_url (first_seen,url,name,category,last_checked) values ('Wed Jan 28 21:15:40 2015','http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/34798/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Isabel-and-Ruben-Toledo-Lipstick/index.tmpl','Isabel and Ruben Toledo Lipstick ','Lipstick','Wed Jan 28 21:15:40 2015')

insert into urls (company_name,url) values ('MAC                                                             ','http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/shaded/168/34798/Products/Lips/Lipstick/Isabel-and-Ruben-Toledo-Lipstick/index.tmpl')
```

Update:
When I put a `next` before the `$dbh->do` call I get the results I expect. So It has something to do with doing a `$dbh->do($insertSQL)` or `$dbh->do($updateSQL)`. Am I suppose to make another call after this before using `$dbh->selectrow_array($selectSQL)` again on the 2nd interation? If so why?

Comment: Yes. Having 2 statements will not be a problem. I've used it in other small programs and have never had any problems. I'm thinking it has something to do with transactions and specifically insertions or updates. By default, per documentation, the AutoCommit flag is enabled so I should not have to call commit after a `do` function. Maybe it's something else here I am missing with the DBI, DBD::Pg and posgresql relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen when you update or insert with an active cursor on the same table.  Also you *really really really* should use [bind parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) or you're courting a SQL injection attack.

Comment: I think updating and inserting is fine based on my past usage of DBI. Thanks for the tip on binding parameters. I will be changing all my sql calls to use this from now on. The wiki page on sql injections was surprisingly pretty thorough: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: In order to better get this question answered you're going to either have to provide a schema dump (with data) that reproduces the problem OR start removing code to get a more minimal example.

Answer (score -1):

You really should add an $sth2->finish(); at the end of your inner while loop, and an $sth->finish(); after your outer while loop.   Not performing a finish on your inner loop can cause the first iteration to work but not all subsequent iterations, just as you describe in your problem.

To say the least, it is bad form to not perform a finish on an sth, although you can get away with it usually if you do not have nested fetches.  Once you have nested fetches without corresponding finishes you run into the exact problem you describe.

Comment: Statement handles will automatically finish when they are destroyed, usually because the variable goes out of scope or it's reassigned to. `$sth2` will finish at the end of each iteration of the loop.  `$sth` will finish at the end of `main`.

Comment: @Schwern how does this affect do statements? Per documentation of DBI and DBD::Pg the `do` function only does a prepare and execute and not a finish. Is the finish implied as well with a `do`? http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#do

Comment: @Nick.D A `do` has no cursor to finish, it just executes the statement and tells you how many rows were effected. `selectall_*` will finish for you (either explicitly or by letting the internal statement handle fall out of scope). Basically, [only call finish when you A) know you're not going to fetch all the data and B) you know the handle will not be destroyed soon](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#finish). Using `prepare_cached` makes things a little bit more complicated, but it will warn you if you reuse an active handle.